# Naming convention for Enterprise Integration Patterns (EIP) component?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-integration, enterprise-integration

Do we have naming convention from Enterprise Integration Patters (EIP) components?

For example, there are so many channels in the integration flow, how should I name the channels?

So far I found this: https://github.com/powertac/powertac-server/wiki/Naming-conventions-for-communication-channels

Do we have more comprehensive naming guide?